# Get image from link (Symfony)

Tags: image, forms, symfony1, upload

I have a problem to upload an image using Symfony.

I have a form where I get the links of banners, those banners are hosted on different websites.

But, I need to save them on my server, how to do it in an action class in Symfony?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an action, use a form!

You create a simple text input, but you use a custom validator extending the **sfValidatorFile** (used for classic file upload). This validator is returning a **sfValidatedFile**, safe and really easy to save with the save() method.

Here is an example code of my own:

```
<?php

/**
 * myValidatorWebFile simule a file upload from a web url (ftp, http)
 * You must use the validation options of sfValidatorFile
 * 
 * @package    symfony
 * @subpackage validator
 * @author     dalexandre
 */
class myValidatorWebFile extends sfValidatorFile
{
  /**
   * @see sfValidatorBase
   */
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);
  }

  /**
   * Fetch the file and put it under /tmp
   * Then simulate a web upload and pass through sfValidatorFile
   * 
   * @param url $value
   * @return sfValidatedFile
   */
  protected function doClean($value)
  {
    $file_content = file_get_contents($value);
    if ($file_content) 
    {
      $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "SL");
      $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
      fwrite($handle, $file_content);
      fclose($handle);

      $fake_upload_file = array();
      $fake_upload_file['tmp_name'] = $tmpfname;
      $fake_upload_file['name']     = basename($value);

      return parent::doClean($fake_upload_file);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid');
    }
  }

  /**
   * Fix a strange bug where the string was declared has empty...
   */
  protected function isEmpty($value)
  {
    return empty ($value);
  }
}
```